# Arrow under a limit sign in text mode

Tags: equations, arrows

I want to write an arrow under a limit in text mode, something like this:[image]

If I put the limit under double dollars or in equation mode, I can do this with $$\lim_{\xrightarrow i}$$, but I'd rather not put this expression into a line of its own. How can I do this?

Comment: I just mean that I'd like the expression with the limit to remain within the paragraph of text.

Comment: Hm, probably in the amsmath package. It's just an arrow variant as far as I know. I didn't mean that command specifically, any arrow would do the job if the limit is in the equation environment. My problem is that, when I write $\lim_{\rightarrow}$ inside a paragraph, the arrow goes to the bottom right angle of the limit sign, instead of directly under it.

Comment: Aren't after writing a *direct limit*, per chance?

Comment: There is also `\varinjlim` from `amsmath` with the arrow built in.  That does leave the question of how to consider the *i*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[cal=euler]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\emph{If} \(\lim\limits_{\longrightarrow i} H^\bullet \mathcal{M}_i(A) \)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I didn't know about the \limits command.